# ZF2 second controller fatal error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

As i'm Following the zf2 2.3 document, everythings work fine until i try to create a new controller called usercontroller and after the setup i encouter this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Album\Controller\UserController' not found in /var/www/html/sites/xxxxx/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 171
```

i already included it in invokables and routes:

```
#invokeables
'invokables' => array(
    'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
    'Album\Controller\User' => 'Album\Controller\UserController',
),


#added user route along with album route
'user' => array(
   'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
     'route'    => '/user[/:action][/:id]',
     'constraints' => array(
         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
         ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\User',
        'action'     => 'index',
        ),
           ),
       ),



#UserController
namespace User\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class UserController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}


#Module.php
namespace Album;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
     public function getAutoloaderConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                 __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
             ),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                 'namespaces' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
         );
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }
 }
```

Comment: In `#UserController` namespace should be `namespace Album\Controller;` and not `namespace User\Controller;` Your `UserController` as defned in the `#invokeables` says that the controller is under `Album` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 
  UserController please **replace your line**

```
     namespace User\Controller;
```

**with**

```
    namespace Album\Controller;
```

Comment: it's not clear to me why still use the namespace Album\Controller, wherein it's a User Controller? thanks btw, that fix the prob.